# Creating a unique hash code based on some properties of an object

Tags: c#, hash, compare

I have to following classes:

```
public class NominalValue
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string ElementName {get; set;}
   public decimal From {get; set;}  
   public decimal To {get; set;}    
   public bool Enable {get; set;}   
   public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
   public int StandardValueId {get; set;}  //FK for StandardValue
} 
public class StandardValue
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string ElementName {get; set;}
   public decimal From {get; set;}  
   public decimal To {get; set;}    
   public bool Enable {get; set;}   
   public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}
```

User wants to fill `nominalValue` object properties. filling the `nominalValue` properties can performed in 2 way:

1. User fill values for `nominalValue` manually.
2. User Load values for `nominalValue` from a `standardValue` object and then change some values or not.

sometimes I need to know if some property of `nominalValue` objects for a specified Element are equal to corresponding `standardValue` or not?

I don't want to load `standardValue` from `Db` for checking this equality, so I decided to define a `HashValue` property in `NominalValue` class:

```
public class NominalValue
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string ElementName {get; set;}
   public decimal From {get; set;}  //<-- 1st parameter for generating hash value
   public decimal To {get; set;}    //<-- 2nd parameter for generating hash value
   public bool Enable {get; set;}   //<-- 3rd parameter for generating hash value 
   public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
   public int StandardValueId {get; set;}  
   public string HashValue {get;set;}      //<-- this property added
}
```

when user fill `nominalValue` properties using `standardValue` properties, I calculate its value based on 3 properties(`From`, `To`, `Enable`) and save it with other properties, and when I check if that `nominalValue` fill with `standardValue` or not, I calculate hash code for `From`, `To`, `Enable` and compare the result with `HashValue` (instead loading `standardValue` from `Db`).

Is there any mechanism to calculate a unique hash code based on 3 property values(`From`, `To`, `Enable`)?

Comment: This is a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden/371348#371348

Answer (score 5):

You can try to do something like this :

```
private int GetHashValue() {
    unchecked 
    {
        int hash = 17;
        //dont forget nullity checks 
        hash = hash * 23 + From.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + To.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Enable.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

You can use the GetHashCode method on an anonymous type too

```
private int GetHashValue() {
   return new { From, To, Enable }.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Magic numbers should always be commented, but especially in a SO answer.

Comment: The idea is to take two different prime numbers, it comes from this book https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321356683

Comment: The GetHashCode from an anonymous object is way more elegant and portable and should be the (separate) accepted answer in my opinion.